# Increase Heap size for hive query

Tags: hive

I recently started working on Hive by using on Unix interface or on SQL workbench.
Sometimes I am facing an error that says "Please increase your Java heap space using Xmx parameter". I think this relates to efficiency of the query. Can anyone give me some context on Heap size and help me increase this ?

Answer (score 2):

The Java heap space in hive is set to a default value of 1024 MB. This is fine for relatively small data and non-intensive queries, but once you start dealing with larger tables and more complex queries, the default value is not enough. Dependent on how much RAM you have available on your machine, I would consider either doubling or tripling the default value up to 2048 MB or 3072 MB.

You can do that by going to the /etc/hive/conf directory and editing the hive-env.sh file there. For you, in that file there'll be a line that looks like

```
export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=1024
```

All you've gotta do is change that value to one of the ones I mentioned. If that's still not enough, keep giving hive incrementally more until your query doesn't fail. Make sure to be cognizant of how much memory you're giving it in regards to how much memory your machine has while you're doing that though.

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks I do not have permission to overwrite or save my changes. My current heap size is at 2000. I will increase this to 4GB

Comment: You could try using "sudo vim hive-env.sh" to edit the file. Also if you could upvote the answer and click on the little check mark beneath the upvote UI it would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

**Increase the heap size**

For example, to increase the heap size to 1GB, set it as

```
mapred.child.java.opts=  -Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 0):

Hs2 will play key role to execute the quires and retrieve the data from filesystem. please follow below link for best practices of Hs2 heap recommendations.

[Hiveserver2 Heap Size Recommendations](https://hadoopcdp.com/hive-server2-heap-size-recommendations/)